# javascript initialize the result of a function outside of the function block, fcc test

Tags: javascript, function, global-variables

INTRODUCTION

Let be a recursive function that pushes values in an array.
I initialize the array out of the function block. The fact that the array is initialized outside of the function block should not be a problem d/t the property of JavaScript functions to manipulate variables defined outside of their scope.
See below, the same snippet into 2 versions, the first with array in general scope, the second with 2 nested functions. the result is also pasted, it is the same.
But this code doesn't pass the test in [fcc exercise](http://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/bonfire-steamroller) when the array is initialized outside of the function block.

**- the first snippet: doesn't pass the test.**

```
var newArr = [];
function steamroller(arr) {

    while (arr.length > 0) {

      if (Array.isArray(arr[0])) {
       steamroller(arr[0]);   
      }  
      else {newArr.push(arr[0]);
      console.log("newArr ", newArr);
      }
      arr.shift();
    }
  // I'm a steamroller, baby
  return newArr;
}

steamroller([1, {}, [3, [[4]]]]);
```

*and  its output:*

```
    Native Browser JavaScript

newArr  [ 1 ]
newArr  [ 1, {} ]
newArr  [ 1, {}, 3 ]
newArr  [ 1, {}, 3, 4 ]
=> [ 1, {}, 3, 4 ]
```

**- the second snippet pass the test:**

```
    function steamroller(arr) {//1
    var newArr = [];
function ude(arr){//2
    while (arr.length > 0) {//3
      if (Array.isArray(arr[0])) {//4
       ude(arr[0]);   
      }//4c  
      else {newArr.push(arr[0]);
      console.log("newArr ", newArr);
      }//3c
      arr.shift();
    }
  // I'm a steamroller, baby
  return newArr;
}
return ude(arr);
}
steamroller([1, {}, [3, [[4]]]]);
```

and his output:

```
Native Browser JavaScript


newArr  [ 1 ]
newArr  [ 1, {} ]
newArr  [ 1, {}, 3 ]
newArr  [ 1, {}, 3, 4 ]
=> [ 1, {}, 3, 4 ]
```

THE QUESTION:

What is the difference?

Comment: The problem is that the result is *not* right when you call the function multiple times. If you've added that `steamroller([1, {}, [3, [[4]]]]);` line in your snippet, it always will fill your array up even before the test. If you don't want to use return values, nest two functions - one that initialises and then returns the array, and one that fills it and might be recursively called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps you a bit. Each object has a built in `toString` method.

[`Array.prototype.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString)

> The `toString()` method returns a string representing the specified array and its elements.
>
> ### Syntax
>
> ```
> arr.toString()
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
>
> None.
>
> ### Description
>
> The Array object overrides the toString method of Object. For Array objects, the toString method joins the array and returns one string containing each array element separated by commas.

Edit:

An example how to use a local array for collecting elements.

```js
function steamroller(arr) {
    var newArr = [];
    while (arr.length) {
        if (Array.isArray(arr[0])) {
            newArr = newArr.concat(steamroller(arr[0]));
        } else {
            newArr.push(arr[0]);
        }
        arr.shift();
    }
    return newArr;
}
document.write('<pre>' + steamroller([1, {}, [3, [[4]]]]) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(steamroller([1, {}, [3, [[4]]]]), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the program is tested by the browser with many successive values.
But the array called "newArray" is not reinitialized between two tests, because it does not reset when she is a global variable, whenever we launch function. Quite simply.